# Send to individual devices giving an error when function is run locally

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that [sends a message to devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices):

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload, options)
    .then(function() {
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

This works without an error when the function is deployed but when it is run locally (`firebase serve --only functions`) it gives this error:

> An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make
>   sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper
>   permissions.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Might not be your case, but for me what happened was that I was generating the key for crash reporting instead of admin sdk. (Idk how I did it, I think I followed the wrong link when I was confirming the invitation). I noticed that in the json file, the value of client_email was something like firebase-crashreporting-.....  Instead it should be something like firebase-adminsdk-....

Comment: @Freaya : how do you configure the local config variable to run locally FCM function ?  (wich key/value to put ) ?